# is it possible to host windows powershell on a .netcore app

Tags: powershell, .net-core

i was wondering if it is possible to host Windows PowerShell on a .NetCore application assuming that i'm gonna use it on Windows OS, but couldn't find an answer for that.

anyone knows if there's a way to do that?

Comment: PowerShell Core 6 does not run only on Windows. This could be an interesting read for you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/what-s-new-in-powershell-core-60?view=powershell-6

Comment: yeah but Windows powershell  has modules which are not supported on powershell core, thats why i asked for windows powershell. @TobyU

Comment: Then it is sadly not possible.

Comment: i see.. thanks! @TobyU

Comment: @gil Is you're question "can I host powershell in a .netcore app?" or "will I be able to use Windows PowerShell modules that ship with Windows from PowerShell Core?"? - two very different questions

Comment: will I be able to use Windows PowerShell modules that ship with Windows from PowerShell Core is what i meant, thanks for clearifying my question @MathiasR.Jessen

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible.

**Windows PowerShell** only runs on Windows, **PowerShell Core** runs on Windows, Mac OS and Linux.

You'll find more information about that in this article: https://www.ghacks.net/2018/01/12/powershell-vs-powershell-core-what-you-need-to-know/